# HTML / CSS - DIV Element hidden when it shouldn't be?

Tags: css, html, visibility

[image]

(clickable)

Mainad has a valid height and width, however it isn't shown like subad1/subad2. Which are in essence exactly the same! (just a different background image).

Firebug shows my div as greyed out for some weird reason. Replacing the contents of mainad with just some text doesn't solve the problem (problem isn't related to inner elements)..

What's going on?! :(

Comment: Do you have a URL we could look at?

Comment: + 1 for the URL or maybe you could show the complete HTML?

Comment: @RoBorg - I prefer not to get the website URL indexed by search engines just yet. Sorry :(

Comment: @Daniel - upload it with a cryptic name, to a cryptic directory. It's much easier to diagnose a functional issue than it is a screenshot of code.

Comment: I went to your example link and the mainad div shows up fine on the page and in firebug.

Comment: @John

It works in IE (possibly other browsers) I have just figured.
Doesn't work in FireFox though.

Comment: Are you running AdBlock?

Comment: Did you fix it?  I went there, saw the error... refreshed it and the 'xxx' was replaced with other text and the error was gone

Comment: @John:

Oh boy.... Adblock was indeed running with this filter:
#*(mainad)

Damn! Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe, just maybe.. you're missing speech marks somewhere or some other required code, I have had the same issue before spent hours trying to figure it out - only to find I left out one set of speech marks, worth checking!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do you have AdBlock installed? That might be hiding that div.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me crazy. I was checking all the markup and nothing worked.

Comment: uBlock origin caused the same error on my site. Guess it blocks anything marked ad.

Comment: Same problem this really sucks XD They cannot block a div just caues you accidently use the keyword "ad" in the classname.

Answer (score 3):

An extra little note:  FireBug will actually show something like this in the Style pane when AdBlock Plus is blocking it (wrapped for clarity):

```
.mainad, #mainad {             undefined (line 233)
    -moz-binding:url(chrome://global/content/bindings/
     general.xml?abphit:707307897865#basecontrol) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebug displays selectors without HTML content, or block element styles as gray. If you edit the HTML, and add some copy you will see the selector regain its colors.