# Background image of li element not showing in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have an html portion of code in my page that goes something like this:

```
<section class ="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li class="facebook">Facebook</li>
                <li class="linkedin">LinkedIn</li>
                <li class="twitter">Twitter</li>
                <li class="google-plus">Google+</li>
            </ul>
</section>
```

And the css goes like this:

```
    .sidebar ul {
    float: left;
}

.sidebar ul li{
    display: block;
    width:35px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin: 3px;
}

li.facebook{
    height: 35px;
    background: url(img/icon_face.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
li.twitter{
    height: 35px;
    background: url(img/icon_twitter.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
li.google-plus{
    height: 35px;
    background: url(img/icon_g+.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;

}
li.linkedin{
    height: 35px;
    background: url(img/icon_in.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

What happens here is that I have  2 strange issues:

First the element li.google-plus does not show in any of the browsers. The browsers just ignore it. Here is what firebug shows:

[image: Google-plus element disabled]

The second is that the only image that shows in firefox is the twitter one. In chrome and opera all the other ones show correctly. As they are showing correctly in other browsers I assume the problem is not the path in the background property.

Any idea on what the problem may be?

EDIT:

Check what firebug says about the background image path:

[image: firebug says 'Can't load given url']

It says that it couldn't load the given url.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: or can you post your actual page?

Comment: Any difference when you use `'` within the url definition? Like so: `url('img/icon_in.png')`.

Comment: why you are giving width in `.sidebar ul li` and height in `li.facebook,li.twitter` etc.

Comment: @BramVanroy: `background:url(*.png)` does not contain quote (`'`)

Comment: maybe superstition, but the + in your filename for the background img url may be causing issues. Have you tried escaping your url like `background: url("img/icon_g+.png") center center no-repeat;`.  Using other images your code works.  http://jsfiddle.net/Axrgd/

Comment: @StephenJames Your superstition was right :) removing the '+' actually did solve the google-plus problem.

Comment: @j08691 http://jsfiddle.net/vu7fJ/1/ here is the code with the isolated issue. I can't actually put the whole code as my companiy has some strict privacy policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that the problem was my AdBlock extension. After disabling it, it started working normally.

Figured it out through this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/466020/1235708

Answer (score 0):

Both in `.sidebar ul li` and in `li.facebook,li.twitter` etc. You should write `width:` and `height:` properties which You didn't set.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. But setting those attributes in both didn't solve the issue.